# Dev browser load time slow - decrease vendor.js file size?

Tags: angular, webpack

Using Angular 8.0,

My browser load time with ng serve is about 15 seconds.

My browser load time with ng serve --prod is about 4 seconds.

In of the main differences that I see to cause the slow load time in dev is there is a vendor.js file that is 7 MB large.

What can be done to make the browser load time for dev less and closer to what I get to the prod build? Could some kind of modification be done to the tool chain where the vendor.js file is smaller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing I have in mind is you probably depend on a lot of 3rd parties which not really tree-shakable.

Try loading using the `optimizer` in 'serve' as well.

In your angular.json file:

```
...
"serve": {
   "options": {
      "optimization": true
  }

}
```

You can also set up the `aot` prop to `true` just keep in mind that every save will build your app in AOT mode.

Hope that's help :)

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot! Now I get about 10 sec vs the previous 16. Anything else I can do to make dev come close the the prod 4 second load time?

Comment: you can run the production build in serve anytime or by setting it in your angular.json file or just use the `ng serve --prod`.

Comment: But, I would give a try to fix that in dev mode, running serve in production is not really recommended

Comment: I thought about that...the only issue is that I am offsetting the time to the compile time which takes 2 minutes to compile on a single change.